# What's the glob that matches all ~/xy* except for ~/xyz*?

Tags: zsh, wildcards

This won't work: `~/xy*~~/xyz*`.

I know that `$HOME/xy*~$HOME/xyz*` works, but I'd like to know if there's a way to achieve the same effect with path prefixes that begin with `~`, such as `~/` or `~user/` or `~nameddir/`.

Comment: with bash extglob  `xy?([^z]*)` will work, not sure equivalent in zsh

Comment: @don_crissti: what you wrote at the end of your comment is the answer to my question; I'll gladly accept it if you post it as such.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you're expecting the shell to expand the tilde into `$HOME` both in the beginning and somewhere in the middle of a word which won't happen: the 1st `~` will be expanded into `$HOME` but not the others (in this case, due to `extendedglob` being set, they are treated as glob operators )...
As noted, there are ways to do it - even *Sundeep*'s suggestion is OK because `zsh` understands `ksh`-like globs (which is where `bash` copied them from):

```
setopt kshglob
setopt nobareglobqual
print -rl ~/xy?([^z]*)
```

Answer (score 3):

[`~` is only expanded in very few contexts](/a/146697).

Here, you can do `~/xy^z*` or `~/xy(*~z*)`.

Answer (score 2):

You can perform the negation:

```
~/(xy|xy[^z]*)
```

or shorter:

```
~/xy(|[^z]*)
```

Comment: @Gilles doesn't that just list anything not starting with `z`?

Comment: Yes, because I made a stupid typo, sorry.