# ~ glob operator behavior with empty pattern

Tags: zsh, wildcards

Per the documentation, `~` [can be used as *glob operator*](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Expansion.html#Filename-Generation) when `EXTENDED_GLOB` is set, allowing constructs like

```
print -rl glob*~globA*~glob*B
```

so anything that matches `glob*` but does not match `globA*` and `glob*B`.
All right:

```
touch file{1,2,3,4{,5}}
setopt extendedglob
```

now

```
print -rl file*~f*3~file4*
```

behaves as expected:

```
file1
file2
```

but when an empty pattern is used

```
print -rl file*~f*3~~file4*
```

prints

```
file1
file2
file3
```

It looks like only the last pattern is used to filter the results of the 1st glob (2nd and 3rd - which is empty - are ignored).

```
print -rl file*~f*3~file4*~~
```

produces

```
file1
file2
file4
file45
```

so now only the 2nd one is used...
What's weird is that if the pattern after the 1st tilde is empty it does not work at all e.g.

```
print -rl file*~~f*3~file4*
```

errors out with

```
zsh: no matches found: file*~~f*3~file4*
```

What am I missing here ?

---

this is with `zsh 5.3.1` if it matters...

Comment: It *looks* like `~~` is literal and not an operator.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`~~` doesn't use an empty pattern. Instead, it does one of two things:

- At the end of the whole pattern, literally matches "`~~`".
- In the middle, literally matches a single "`~`", then moves on to the next excluded pattern (i.e. a literal `~` followed by the `~` operator).

If we extend your file set with a few extras we can see that happen:

```
touch file3~ file3~~ file4~ file4~~
```

Now running your first odd command:

```
print -rl file*~f*3~~file4*
file1
file2
file3
file3~~
```

`file3~` has been excluded, as have all three `file4*`s. `file3~~` is still there, because it doesn't match `f*3~`.

The second one:

```
print -rl file*~f*3~file4*~~
file1
file2
file3~
file3~~
file4
file45
file4~
```

Only `file4~~` has been excluded, because that's the only one matching `file4*~~`.

The final case now does have output:

```
print -rl file*~~f*3~file4*
file3~
file3~~
```

since those are the two files matching `file*~` that don't match either `f*3` or `file4*`.

Perhaps this could be a parsing bug, at least for the literal-then-operator case, but I can't see a use for an empty exclusion pattern so I'm not sure what else it should do.

Comment: Thanks ! I can't see a use for an empty pattern either but I was just playing with it [after reading this question](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/347343) and was rather confused by the results...